# How to hide multiple images and show only one image?

Tags: javascript

I have many buttons and each one must show a different image when that particular button is clicked. The issue is that when a button is clicked, it shows the new image as well as the image from the previous button. How can I hide all the previous images and only show the one that's attached to the button that was most recently clicked?

```
 <button class="colour-btn colour-btn--3" id="3" onClick="showImage3()"></button>
 <button class="colour-btn colour-btn--8" onClick="showImage8()"></button>
```

```
function showImage3() {
    showImage3 = function () {}
    var img3 = document.createElement('img')
    img3.setAttribute("src", "")
    img3.setAttribute("width", "700")
    img3.setAttribute("height", "400")
    document.body.appendChild(img3)
}


function showImage8() {
    showImage8 = function () {}
    var img8 = document.createElement('img')
    img8.setAttribute("src", "")
    img8.setAttribute("width", "600")
    img8.setAttribute("height", "400")
    document.body.appendChild(img8)
}
```

Comment: create a div where the images will be displayed and everytime you need a new image you empty the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear why do you need separate functions here. You can use data-* attribute and based on that you can set the style property. You can set all the previous images style to `none` using `querySelectorAll()` and `forEach()`.

Also you probably do want to append image again if it is already in the DOM, in that case instead of appending again you can simply show that.

**Demo:**

```js
function showImage(el) {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  Array.from(images).forEach(i => i.style.display = 'none');
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.setAttribute("src", "");
  var dataId = el.getAttribute('data-id');
  if(dataId == '3'){
    img.setAttribute("width", "700");
    img.setAttribute("height", "400");
  }
  else if(dataId == '8'){
    img.setAttribute("width", "600");
    img.setAttribute("height", "400");
  }
  if(document.querySelector(`img[data-id="${dataId}"]`)){
    document.querySelector(`img[data-id="${dataId}"]`).style.display = 'block';
  }
  else{
    img.setAttribute('data-id', dataId);
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  }
  console.log('current image:', el.getAttribute('data-id'));
}
```

```html
<button class="colour-btn colour-btn--3" data-id="3" onClick="showImage(this)">3</button>
<button class="colour-btn colour-btn--8" data-id="8" onClick="showImage(this)">8</button>
```